# Voltage Regulation and Capacitors

Tags: capacitor, voltage-regulator

Currently I am building my own AVR dev board, and I have been looking online about how to build the voltage regulator. I can build it, but I am curious as to why a capacitor is necessary. Also what devices how much capacitance you need?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many regulators will oscillate if the capacitor on the output is omitted, or if it is too far from the regulator, and not regulate properly. I've actually seen this happen: a friend of mine copied a power supply design of mine, left off the output capacitors on the regulators, and found that one of them was only delivering a couple of volts. The data sheet will have details of the capacitors that are required.

Comment: Not just seen it happen, it's one of the first things to look for if a new board isn't powering up right.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great help. Could you also explain possibly why this is the case? It's just that I like to understand exactly what the thing does that I'm making. (It helps a lot with troubleshooting)

Comment: Regulators contain a high-gain DC amplifier.

Comment: @LeonHeller, why does the regulator oscillate and how does the capacitor help to suppress it?

Comment: Unwanted feedback between the input and output can cause oscillation which is prevented by the capacitor shunting high frequencies to ground.

Answer (score 0):

A voltage regulator is equivalent to a variable resistor. It follows with the voltage change of the output terminal and regulate at a fixed value. From this point, the regulator's equivalent resistor and load resistor form a voltage divider.

But there is a response time on regulator, so the output voltage will jump (swing) around the fixed value.

The capacitor is a energy storage device, and the voltage across the capacitor can not change instantaneously. So if you want to get a smooth change, a capacitor is needed.

You also need to know, the capacitor have an [equivalent series resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalent_series_resistance) (ESR), and this will cause ripple. To reduce this, chose a low-ESR capacitor, or a few capacitors in parallel. (But for some circuits, a low-ESR capacitor will cause the circuit to oscillate.)

The wire also has a resistance, and it will cause ripple when you're using the capacitor. So you need place the capacitor close to the output pin of the regulator IC.